# How do I make banners with more than 6 layers

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-legacy-console

I want to make a banner for my sister from Planet Minecraft, but I can't create a banner with more than 6 layers. I'm not sure if the console has Command Blocks, but I don't wanna waste my time typing in all of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is absolutely no way to get past this 6 layer limit, as commands are not available in legacy console. Legacy console's version of commands is host privileges, which is extremely limited and has not item-giving capabilities.

Every single other answer is wrong.

Comment: Can't you "simply" edit the world NBT with a third-party tool? Every console that has a Legacy Console version also has a Homebrew community, after all. (Edit: Realized I should probably put "simply" in quotes, as finding the right tools can be a mess.)

Comment: @EgorHans yeah you probably can if you use a computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do without commands.

You can use [this tool](https://www.needcoolshoes.com/banner?=paap) to generate a command for you that creates the banner.

Yes, the console edition has command blocks. You can get one by entering `/give @p command_block` into the chat.

Comment: How do you enable the chat, though? I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: There should be a key. The wiki says it's the right arrow key by default.

Comment: But if you don't know how to do that, you probably also didn't enable cheats, so then you would be unable to use (most) commands, including this one.

Comment: Wait, is this for PS4? If it is, then I don't know about the right arrow key and how to enable cheats. Any tips on where those are on the DUALSHOCK 4 or the PS4 Console?

Comment: I did some research and found out that console edition is real crap. Once again. Anyway, I don't know, the wiki states many different controls for all kinds of devices. Maybe just try all the keys?

Comment: Are you on the BTU update for Minecraft?

Comment: The ones with the banners and parrots? Because I don't remember.

Comment: What is the version number?

Answer (score -1):

Creative, singleplayer, and commands are the only way at the moment to make banners with more than 6 layers. At least without the multiplayer survival server having a plugin that will override Mojang's coded 6 layer limit. BUT, they are in the process to raise this limit for banners.

Command blocks are too redundant, not to mention most servers have the use of command blocks turned off but since just typing the command in chat will give you any number of banners you may need. I use this site for including banners [Minecraft Tools including Custom Banners](https://minecraft.tools/en/banner.php)

Answer (score -1):

There's only 3 ways in survival. Commands, command blocks or the multiplayer server would need to have a plugin installed, like BetterBanner plugin, to bypass Mojang's hard coded 6 layer limit.